# Android right aligned LinearLayout strange animations on layout change

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

I have a right aligned linearlayout attached to a window (I am using a service)

```
LinearLayout ll =  new LinearLayout(this);

llp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE);
    llp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.addView(ll, llp);
```

It has two elements in it: an ImageView and a TextView.

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, fixedHeight);
    textView = new TextView(this);
ll.addView(textView, textParam);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(fixedWidth, fixedHeight);
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    ll.addView(imageView, imageParam);
```

This all works as expected, and image is on the far right and a text snippet is to the left of the image. However after a set amount of time I hide the text snippet.

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I would have thought doing so would have no effect on the imageView as the imageView is on the far right.

However it appears there is some sort of built in animation on layoutchanges which makes the imageview jump to the left most point of the linearlayout and animate back to its original position.

Does anyone know how to disable that animation? I have looked into it and thought something like this would do it:

```
ll.setLayoutTransition(null);
```

But it has no effect. I also found this suggestion:

```
LayoutTransition lt = new LayoutTransition();
lt.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING);
mContainerView.setLayoutTransition(lt);
```

That changed the animation actually making it a bit worse for my case.

If anyone has any information on how to disable all layoutchange animations or even any information on them it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?